# PyCharm and proper type hinting of class objects

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

System:
- Windows 10 x64
- Python 3.6 x64
- PyCharm 2017.3.4

I am trying to better understand Python type annotation as relates to specifying class objects, rather than instances of classes.  Suppose I have a super class and a sub class and I want to loop over a list of class objects and instantiate one of each.

In the code below I can get proper code-completion and tooltips in PyCharm when instantiating from the class directly or from a direct alias (using `Ctrl-P` for example).  However, if I loop over the list and provide a type annotation (using `typing.Type[Super1]`) for the iterating variable `cls` it seems to annotate it as an instance, rather than as a class object.  So I get proper code completion for the methods and properties, but then I don't get tooltips for the function arguments for the initialization.

How do I annotate it as a set of classes, rather than an instance of a set of classes (i.e. this variable is either the `Super1` class or a sub-class of `Super1`).  Is this the proper way but PyCharm just isn't recognizing it properly or is there actually a different way to do this.

```
import typing

class Super1:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.meta = "super class"

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

class Sub1(Super1):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super(Sub1, self).__init__(name)
        self.meta = "sub class"


super_instance = Super1("name")  # <-- get proper type hints in PyCharm
sub1_alias = Sub1
sub1_alias("name")  # <-- get proper type hints for the __init__ function in PyCharm

cls: typing.Type[Super1]
for cls in (Super1, Sub1):
    inst = cls("name")  # <-- Ctrl-P does not give proper type hints for the __init__ function in PyCharm
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a bug in annotation support, I created a ticket in PyCharm bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29265

Comment: Thanks very much, I suppose that answers the question in that typing.Type is the appropriate way to annotate a class

Comment: It has been more than 3 years and the problem is still there